# Java strings arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I'm having trouble with my program. I need to enter only capital letters, R,B,W. Validate the correct input and then sort the string. Output should be sorted with R's first, B's second and W's third. I can only get the alphabetized output, not the needed output. I don't know what to do next.

```
System.out.print("Enter a string of capital letters made up of R, B, W:  ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String letters;

for (letters = s.nextLine(); !letters.matches("[RBW]+"); letters = s.nextLine())
{
    System.out.println("Invalid entry. Please enter the correct letters.");
}

System.out.println("Thank you");
char[] sort2 = letters.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(sort2);
String sorted = new String(sort2);

System.out.println("Here are your letters sorted:" +sorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Have three different `StringBuilder`s and add each letter to them accordingly. Then concatenate them in the right order when its done looping through the letters.

```
StringBuilder r = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder w = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

for (char c : letters.toCharArray()){
    switch(c){
        case 'R' : r.append(c); break;
        case 'B' : b.append(c); break;
        case 'W' : w.append(c); break;
    }
}

String sorted = r.toString() + b.toString() + w.toString();
System.out.println("Here are your letters sorted:" + sorted);
```

Comment: @Chris I was thinking of a more complex solution too, but then I was thinking, there's gotta be an easier way ;)

Comment: WOW! Great solution! I have been struggling on this for a while now. This makes logical sense.

Comment: Thank you!This was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays.sort(char[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) uses [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so you'll get Bs then Rs then Ws.

If you want an other sort order you have to implement your own Comparator and use [Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Therefore you have to convert it to an Object array.

```
Arrays.sort(sort2, new Comparator<Char>() {
    public int compare(Char o1, Char o2) {
        if (Char.valueOf("R").equals(o1)) {
            if (Char.valueOf("R").equals(o2)) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (Char.valueOf("B").equals(o1)) {
        ....

    }
});
```